# Linq-to-Sql case insensitive code generation

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is there a way to configure the way linq-to-sql generates the property names in a stored precedure result. I want them all upper case independent from the upper and lower case that were used in the stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you can do that by editing the DBML file.